# Rearranging div tags within one another

Tags: css

I want to rearrange the div tags (shown below) between one another. How can I do that?

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
        This has less height
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This has more height
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This has less height.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With CSS alone, you can't.

Comment: how do you need them to be arranged can you show us a mohup? do you have some CSS code?

Comment: 1) What do you mean? How do you want them arranged? Im not sure what you're asking. Do you want to organize the div's manually or automatically through JavaScript? Please be more specific. More specific questions = more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

How do you need to rearrange them?

### Float and overflow

You could `float` them to the left or right:

```
.box:nth-child(1) {
  float: right;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ggtsw

This will **not** work for any combination, because the last one need to be the *overflowed* one.

### Using flexbox

Using the new flexbox layout would be very simple since it has an `order` property for exactly that:

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  order: 3;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  order: 2;
}
```

Very easy. Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/keLP9

[Compatibility with browsers](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

[Flexbox at the W3C site](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-flexbox-1-20140325/)